# Создается новая таблица, а не подключается к готовой

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Доброго дня!
Имеется mvc проект, в котором необходимо достать данные из таблицы на MS SQL server,
connectionString выглядит так:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="PrimaryConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source = MSI\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog= MyBase;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Данные из таблицы я получаю, но почему-то не из созданной мной, а из той, которая создается на сервере при запуске приложения, собственно вопрос: как получить данные из своей (заполненной) таблицы, а не из того, что мне предоставляет студия.

Код представления:

```
@using Domain
@model IEnumerable <MyClass>
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Index </title>
</head>
<body>


    <div>
        <h3>Шапка</h3>
        <table>
            <tr class="header">
                <td><p>Владелец</p></td>
                <td><p>Название</p></td>
                <td><p>Описание</p></td>
                <td><p>Дата</p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (MyClass one in Model)
             {
            <tr>
                <td><p>@one.ParentId</p></td>
                <td><p>@one.Title</p></td>
                <td><p>@one.Description</p></td>
                <td><p>@one.Created</p></td>

            </tr>
             }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Собственно контроллер:

```
 Repository repository = new Repository();
            return View(repository.GetMyClass());
```

И Repository:

```
private EFContext context;

        public Repository()
        {
            context = new EFContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClass()
        {
            return context.Collection;
        }

        public MyClass GetById(int Id)
        {
            return context.Collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
```

Comment: Строка соединения на сервере указывает на нужную БД?

Comment: @tym32167, да, и создает в ней дополнительные таблицы.

Comment: @tym32167, MyClasses но это имя я не использую в проекте, нигде.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вы не используете подход Database First на созданной вручную БД? У EF своя логика наименования классов, попробуйте указывать явно имена таблиц через атрибут [DataAnnotations - TableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) у класса MyClass: `[Table("MyClass")]` или со схемой `[Table("MyClass", Schema="dbo")]`.

Comment: Вы используете `MyClass` в контексте данных, который генерирует схему БД при запуске, заменяя `MyClass` на множественное число `MyClasses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Alex Krass за комментарий. `[Table("MyClass", Schema="dbo")]` решило проблему.